# After deleting file and re-creating file, not change creation date in windows

Tags: c#, file

I have c# application. This write log in folder.

below code.

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\EXT_LOG\LOG.txt"))
{
    File.Delete(@"C:\EXT_LOG\LOG.txt");
}

string Data = "xxxxx";
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\EXT_LOG\LOG.txt");
file.WriteLine(Data);
file.Dispose();
file.Close();
```

I delete file, if it exist, and I create file with same name.
when I run program, the creation date of file is not change.

I guess windows any manager or any file table still contain that file.

So, when I delete file, can I delete manager or file table content??

Comment: @GrantWinney Actually you can test this yourself from Windows Explorer. 1) Find an existing old file. 2) delete it 3) Create a new file with the same name 4) New file will have the same **Created** as per old file (assuming you do it sufficient quickly).  See dotnetkid's answer below.  I was surprised myself :)

Comment: The reason for this is to enable safe save. Like what MS WORD does. When application programs auto save, they do not over-write files. Instead, they move old file, and create a replica new file. However, the new file needs to retain the attributes of old file including creation time. Refer to temp files you see with ~ sign before them, enabling hidden files to see this happening.

Answer (score 7):

That's how it works in windows. I have not searched Google for **WHY**. However it seems you can set the creation date of the file through C# using *System.IO.File.SetCreationTime* method.

```
public static void SetCreationTime(
    string path,
    DateTime creationTime
)
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: As dotnetkid mentioned, this is the default windows behaviour. The reason for this behaviour can be found here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172190

Comment: Preserved KB article [Windows NT Contains File System Tunneling Capabilities](https://web.archive.org/web/20150307194932/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172190).

Answer (score 1):

this is how I solve the problem:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(outFile, body);

File.SetCreationTimeUtc(outFile, DateTime.UtcNow);
```