# Files getting created with old file details in Java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to create a simple program which checks if a file was created older than today and delete that file to create a new one . But the creatNewFile method is recreating the file with the old (deleted) files properties . For example the new file also has a creation date of yesterday .

What am i doing wrong here ?

```java
private File createFile() {
    logger.trace("Entering createFile method ");
    File trackerFile = new File("tracker.txt");
    if (!trackerFile.exists()) {
        try {
            logger.debug("File does not exist . New file being created ");
            trackerFile.createNewFile();                
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String dateCreated = df.format(this.getCreationTime(trackerFile).toMillis());
            logger.debug("File exists file creation time is {}" , dateCreated);
            Calendar currCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar fileCreateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            fileCreateCalendar.setTime(df.parse(dateCreated));
            if (currCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > fileCreateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                logger.debug("File exists file not created today , being deleted");
                trackerFile.delete();
                trackerFile.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    logger.trace("Exiting createFile method ");
    return trackerFile;
}
```

Please check out this simple code snippet .. the file is created , deleted and then recreated . The file created at the end has a creation date which is the same as the first file that was deleted . How does this happen ?

```java
public class CreateTempFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            file.delete();
            File newFile = new File("test.txt");
            newFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the old, horrible Calendar and Date classes.

Comment: You can simplify the first part also because createNewFile actually does a check to see if the file already exists, only creating it if it doesn't and returning a boolean indicating whether or not it existed and did nothing or didn't exist and created a file.

Comment: Change the code `trackerFile.delete(); trackerFile.createNewFile();` to `trackerFile.delete(); new File("tracker.txt").createNewFile();`. Instead of using the same `File` object, create a new `File` object to create a new file.

Comment: @sudhirshakya I had tried that and the issue remained . Even if i give a different file name for example test.txt than tracker.log it is still creating the file with a creation date of 23(today -1) which was the creation date of the file i deleted

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku Thank you .. i will be updating the code as per suggestion once i get the core logic working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use similar code to get date / time in order to be sure that you are retrieving the right value (e.g. creation is not modification etc):

```
Path file = "tracker.txt";
BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + fileAttributes.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + fileAttributes.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + fileAttributes.lastModifiedTime());
```

You can find more details in the reference here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Comment: I can see the log for the creation time and when i check in the explorer i am getting the correct details . But let me check this out as well .

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in an older post , the link is given below .

[After deleting file and re-creating file, not change creation date in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227149/after-deleting-file-and-re-creating-file-not-change-creation-date-in-windows)